# How I can calculate multiple means and standard deviations for groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, tidyverse, standard-deviation

I struggled to calculate multiple means and standard deviations for multiple groups in R.

Here is my data:

```
df <- read.table(text="A1   B1  time1   A2  B2  time2   A3  B3  time3
m   p   12  m   p   11  n   q   12
n   q   12  m   p   13  n   q   14
n   q   11  n   p   14  m   p   14
n   q   10  n   q   15  m   p   12
m   p   8   n   q   12  m   p   11
",h=T)
```

I want to calculate mean and SD for A1, B1, A2, B2 , A3, B3 for groups based on time 1,time 2 and time 3. the output of interest is:

```
meanA1m x   meanA2m x   meanA3m x
meanA1n x   meanA2n x   meanA3n x
meanB1p x   meanB2p x   meanB3p x
meanB1q x   meanB2q x   meanB3q x
SDA1m   x   SDA2m   x   SDA3m   x
SDA1n   x   STA2n   x   STA3n   x
SDB1p   x   SDB2p   x   SDB3p   x
SDB1q   x   SDB2q   x   SDB3q   x
```

I have searched to find out a solution, but I was unsuccessful or I might have missed something. Is there any solution on these data?

Comment: Can you please clarify which values should go into calculating `meanA1m`, for example? Is it 12 and 8 from the `time1` column? It's hard to understand your data structure

Comment: @Calum you- thank you. for example, time 1 with A1 and B1. so mean A1m= 10, MeanB1p= 10 and so on

Comment: Why is your data wide? Keep it long and aggregation is simple.

Comment: @Parfait- can you help more please

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using development `tidyr::pivot_longer` to reshape this data, which is in a pretty confusing format:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "A1 B1  time1   A2  B2  time2   A3  B3  time3
m   p   12  m   p   11  n   q   12
n   q   12  m   p   13  n   q   14
n   q   11  n   p   14  m   p   14
n   q   10  n   q   15  m   p   12
m   p   8   n   q   12  m   p   11
", h = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

spec <- tibble(
  .name = colnames(df),
  .value = str_extract(.name, ".*(?=\\d)") %>% recode(time = "value"),
  time = str_extract(.name, "\\d")
)
df %>%
  pivot_longer_spec(spec = spec) %>%
  gather("AB", "AB_val", A, B) %>%
  group_by(AB, time, AB_val) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), SD = sd(value))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#> # Groups:   AB, time [6]
#>    AB    time  AB_val  mean    SD
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A     1     m       10    2.83
#>  2 A     1     n       11    1   
#>  3 A     2     m       12    1.41
#>  4 A     2     n       13.7  1.53
#>  5 A     3     m       12.3  1.53
#>  6 A     3     n       13    1.41
#>  7 B     1     p       10    2.83
#>  8 B     1     q       11    1   
#>  9 B     2     p       12.7  1.53
#> 10 B     2     q       13.5  2.12
#> 11 B     3     p       12.3  1.53
#> 12 B     3     q       13    1.41
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: not sure why I get this error: Error in pivot_longer_spec(., spec = spec) : 
  could not find function "pivot_longer_spec"

Comment: Error: Failed to install 'tidyr' from GitHub:

Comment: please see above please Calum You@

Comment: yes, here it is againpackage ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lifecycle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘assertthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pillar’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘backports’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: Failed to install 'tidyr' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘backports’

Comment: same error Error: Failed to install 'tidyr' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can obtain something similar to what you want:

```
#Adding id column to df    
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)  
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
#Reshape df from wide to long
df2 <- melt(df, id = c("id", "time1", "time2", "time3"))
#Compute the required means and sd.
df2[, .(mean1 = mean(time1), sd1 = sd(time1), 
        mean2 = mean(time2), sd2 = sd(time2),
        mean3 = mean(time3), sd3 = sd(time3)
        ),.(variable, value)]

#Returns
    variable value     mean1       sd1    mean2       sd2    mean3       sd3
 1:       A1     m 10.000000 2.8284271 11.50000 0.7071068 11.50000 0.7071068
 2:       A1     n 11.000000 1.0000000 14.00000 1.0000000 13.33333 1.1547005
 3:       B1     p 10.000000 2.8284271 11.50000 0.7071068 11.50000 0.7071068
 4:       B1     q 11.000000 1.0000000 14.00000 1.0000000 13.33333 1.1547005
 5:       A2     m 12.000000 0.0000000 12.00000 1.4142136 13.00000 1.4142136
 6:       A2     n  9.666667 1.5275252 13.66667 1.5275252 12.33333 1.5275252
 7:       B2     p 11.666667 0.5773503 12.66667 1.5275252 13.33333 1.1547005
 8:       B2     q  9.000000 1.4142136 13.50000 2.1213203 11.50000 0.7071068
 9:       A3     n 12.000000 0.0000000 12.00000 1.4142136 13.00000 1.4142136
10:       A3     m  9.666667 1.5275252 13.66667 1.5275252 12.33333 1.5275252
11:       B3     q 12.000000 0.0000000 12.00000 1.4142136 13.00000 1.4142136
12:       B3     p  9.666667 1.5275252 13.66667 1.5275252 12.33333 1.5275252
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul-  is it possible to remove irrelevant means and sds. For example, I want to have only mean1 and sd1 for A1 and B1  and mean2  and sd2 for A2 and B2 and mean3 and sd3 for A3 and B3.